# Receiving an error when requesting members for an array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int winnings[4] = {0,0,0,0};
int* p_winnings = winnings;

void CalculateGame(int* p_games);

int main()
{
    int games[6] = {12,13,14,23,24,34};
    int* p_games = games;
    int favorite_team,games_played,team1,team2,score1,score2,i;
    ifstream data("DATA11.txt");
    data >> favorite_team >> games_played;
    vector<int> standings(4);
    for (i = 0;i < 4; i++)
        standings[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < games_played;i++)
    {
        data >> team1 >> team2 >> score1 >> score2;
        if (score1 > score2)
            standings[team1 - 1] += 3;
        if (score1 == score2)
            standings[team1-1]++,standings[team2-1]++;
        if (score1 < score2)
            standings[team2-1] += 3;
        for (i = 0; i < games.size();i++)
        {
            int temp1,temp2,temp;
            temp = games[i];
            temp2 = temp % 10;
            temp /= 10;
            if (temp2 == team2 && temp == team1)
                games.erase(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Why when i request for a member(like .size() or .erase() ) of the array games i get an error saying "request for member *_*_ in games which is of a non-class type int [6]"

Answer (score 3):

Plain old C arrays don't have members. So it has no `size` or `erase`. If you *did* want it to have members though, C++11 offers a class called `std::array<T,N>` which can be used in your case by simply doing `std::array<int, 6> games = { ... }`. Note however that `std::array` does not have an `erase` member function, but it has a `size` member function.

Comment: would i be better off using a vector?

Comment: @user1816640 If you want to be able to delete elements, yes. You'll have to use the erase-remove idiom.