# size of array error on C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the array size but I am getting an error. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 int myarray[5];
  cout << "size of array: " << myarray.size() << endl;
  cout << "sizeof array: " << sizeof(myarray) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> error: request for member 'size' in 'myarray', which is of non-class type 'int [5]'|

Comment: I know I've seen a question just like this within the last week or two.

Comment: Why `#include <array>` and then not use `std::array`?

Comment: if you don't like C-way of getting the size, why use C-style array? `std::array`, `std::vector`, `std::valarray`, all of them have `size()`

Comment: And also related [Receiving an error when requesting members for an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777559/receiving-an-error-when-requesting-members-for-an-array?rq=1)

Comment: Where did you hear that you could do `.size()` on an array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Arrays do not have member functions because they are not classes. But if you would use `std::array`  then you could use member function `size`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  std::array<int, 5> myarray;

  cout << "size of array: " << myarray.size() << endl;
  cout << "sizeof array: " << sizeof(myarray) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If you indeed want to deal with an array then the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int myarray[5];

    std::cout << "sizeof myarray: " 
              << sizeof( myarray ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "size of myarray: " 
              << sizeof( myarray ) / sizeof( *myarray ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "size of myarray: " 
              << std::extent<decltype( myarray )>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof myarray: 20
size of myarray: 5
size of myarray: 5
```

Pay attention to standard class `std::extent` declared in header `<type_traits>`

Answer (score 8):

It's important to try to understand the errors the compiler gives you, here it's saying:

> error: request for member 'size' in 'myarray', which is of non-class type 'int [5]'|

Which means that you tried to do `myarray.size` but `myarray` is not a class, it's an `int[5]`.

This isn't Java, arrays don't have a `size` method.
Instead you can use `sizeof` to get the raw size in bytes, and `std::extent<decltype(myarray)>::value` (in header `<type_traits>`) for the number of elements.

Note that as mentioned by Vlad, you'll want to use an actual `std::array` to have a size function, this is different from the raw array you used, and probably what you wanted.

Comment: @SeanKuhlman I'm stealing your comment, if you don't mind!

Comment: The OP included the `<array>` header, I think they wanted to use that instead of a C-style array.

Comment: @LB-- Yes, but I'm hesitant to start talking about that now that there's Vlad'd excellent answer! I'll mention it.

Comment: Pretty good answer, _except_... why does everybody keep promoting this `sizeof(ar)/sizeof(*ar)` garbage? Instead write a function template whose specialisations take a `const T (&)[N]` and return `N`. Your `sizeof` trick is extremely error prone, especially for language newcomers who may not realise when array name decay is taking place.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit True. Although templates syntax may be confusing to newcomers too. I think I'd just use the `std::array`.

Comment: @tux3 or we could use the C++ [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) instead of doing this C style

Comment: @Mgetz Yeah I think I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C++ are not classes with member functions. If you want a class, consider using the STL class vector.

Comment: _"Arrays in C++ are not classes with member functions."_ [I beg to differ, sir](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: I will amend that to the array the original poster is using is not a class.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
(sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(*myarray))
```

instead of:

```
myarray.size()
```